# Adding a comment in the middle of a call chain

Tags: ruby, comments

How can I add a comment in the middle of a call chain?

I see that Ruby throws parse error when I try to add a comment in the middle of a call chain like:

```
Tag.joins(:taggings)
   # Wanted to add comment here cause it's long 
   # and takes multiple lines
   .where(...)
   .where(...)
   .where(...)
   # And here
   .group(...)
   .order(...)
```

Comment: This is valid Ruby syntax in Ruby 2.7. Comment lines can be placed between fluent dot now (but no empty lines). See https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/3a3f48fb8fbdbb810d9b675159529970015316b9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change to this structure:

```
Tag.joins(:taggings).
   # Comment 1
   # Comment 2
   where(...).
   where(...).
   where(...).
   # And here
   group(...).
   order(...)
```

Method `.` Dot at end will instruct the parser that expression hasn't ended and logical method chain will arrive.

Comment: Not just the parser, it's also a hint for programmers who might not expect a statement to continue after a (multi-line) comment.

Answer (score 3):

Um, don't do that? Instead, use methods to break things up into smaller pieces of logic that have descriptive names:

```
def add_that_long_thing_to(query)
  # Wanted to add comment here cause it's long 
  # and takes multiple lines
  query.where(...)
       .where(...)
       .where(...)
end

def add_grouping_and_ordering_to_query)
  # And here
  query.group(...)
       .order(...)
end

query = Tag.joins(:taggings)
query = add_that_long_thing_to(query)
query = add_grouping_and_ordering_to(query)
```

Of course, those names would be more sensible in real life but we don't know what any of the code is actually doing so I had to make something up.

Comment: In Rails, you would typically use [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

Comment: @Stefan Sure but a scope is a bit much if you're only using it in one place.

Comment: @muistooshort : Your example would be syntactically invalid. Ruby would consider the statement to be ended after `query.where(...)`. One possibility to force Ruby into recognizing that the `.where` in the next line also belongs to this expression, is to wrap everything between parentheses. This also helps the reader to understand that the whole stuff is one single expression.

Comment: I consider adding extra methods and variables when there is no need for it as an anti-pattern, it's much harder to read actually

Comment: @user1934428: No, that's perfectly valid Ruby.

Comment: @Vedmant You're welcome to your opinion but I'd say the same about trying to mash everything into one pile. Of course, we're throwing around a lot of generalities here, what makes sense in one specific case might not make sense in another regardless of what the rules of thumb have to say.

Comment: @muistooshort : Oops, you seem to be right - I tried it out and indeed no syntax error. This surprises me because (for instance [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_syntax.htm)) says: *Ruby interprets semicolons and newline characters as the ending of a statement. However, if Ruby encounters operators, such as +, −, or backslash at the end of a line, they indicate the continuation of a statement*. Since there is no such "continuation" on your first line, I have assumed that the statement ends here, and the line starting with a dot should give a syntax error.

Comment: @user1934428 Ruby used to require the dot at the end of the line but it was changed to allow it at the beginning of the next line because (AFAIK) it is more readable than having the punctuation hidden way off to the right.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use Ruby < 2.7 *and* want to keep the leading dot position *and* you can limit yourself to single line comments, then backslashes `\` will enable comments in between lines:

```rb
Tag.joins(:taggings) \
   # Wanted to add comment here
   .where(...) \
   .where(...) \
   .where(...) \
   # And here
   .group(...) \
   .order(...)
```

Ruby 2.7 allows multiple comment lines (but no empty lines) between fluent dots. See https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/3a3f48fb8fbdbb810d9b675159529970015316b9 .